# Photoshop CS6: Export data sets as jpg?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, jpg

just stumbled over this site, perhaps somebody here can be of assistance.

I've been creating a large data set to create a large number of separate files with similiar layout. Works great so far, the only thing is that I'd like to export my data sets as jpg instead of psd.

Of course I can simply export them as psd and the convert them with the image processor to jpg, but since my master file is rather large the psd export ends up with lots of large files and the process takes a lot of time.

Is there any way to export data sets directly to jpg (of course by reducing all layers to one)?

Thanks for hints,
Christian aka SirWillibald

Comment: A few things come to mind: **1.** It could probably be scripted. **2.** You could perhaps use Imagemagick to convert psd to jpg. **3.** Use illustrator or indesign instead. **4.** Before exporting data sets, try to flatten as much of the psd as you can and if the jpg size is supposed to be smaller than the psd, match that size. **---** Perhaps the best option out of all of these would be to use illustrator or indesign to do this. I do get that it might be too late for that now, but in the future you should consider that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the hints, I also figured it might have been better to use InDesign, but it's really too late, that would mean to do massive conversions. Thanks anyway, trying the flatten thing, might work!